# asp.net scroll to Anchor on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a couple of buttons where one is scrolling to the top of the page:

```
function topFunction() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

And the other scrolls to the certain anchor:

```
function Intro1Function() {
    document.getElementById('Intro1').scrollIntoView(true);
}
```

I also have blurry background behind the header like this:

```
   var pageContent = document.getElementById("mainContent"),
   pagecopy = pageContent.cloneNode(true),
   blurryContent = document.getElementById("blurryscroll");
   blurryContent.appendChild(pagecopy);
   window.onscroll = function () {
       blurryContent.scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
   }
```

While I scroll to the top, I get a smooth scroll of both content and blurred content.

However, I am unable to scroll both when navigating to anchor. Only Blurred content is scrolled and not the main content.

I am very beginner in asp.net layout coding and have no js knowledge whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function that does exactly this on w3cschools, https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_animate_smoothscroll